# How to display dynamically generated images in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a python Django project where I am generating a huge number of images and displaying them in the front end. Each image generated is labeled as 0.png, 1.png, etc. Every time the number of images generated varies. The images are saved in the static folder. Right now I have in my index.html template.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
   {% for plot in plots%}
      {% with plot|add:".png" as image_static %}
          <ul class="myList"><li><img src="{% static image_static %}" alt="My image"/></li></ul>
      {% endwith %}
   {% endfor %}
```

My views.py looks like below

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    count=Genplots.main() # main function to generate images
    p=list(range(count)) #number of images
    p=map(str,p)
    return render_to_response("plots/index.html", { 'plots':p})
```

I am trying to find a way in which I can generate the images in the background and display the images in front end as they are getting generated asynchronously without waiting for the image generation to complete as it takes a lot of time. Can you please tell me how to do it in the frontend as well as backend? And what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two Django snippets that would help you to create a numeric for loop so that every time it loops `1` is added to the image name, so you'd get 0.jpg, 1.jpg etc.. You'll need to create a template filter

1. https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/
2. https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/779/

Another solution would be if you create a context dict for the range, maybe you could get the `count()` of how many images you have saved and in your view you would have something like this going on:

```
...
render_to_response('foo.html', {..., 'range': range(10), ...}, ...)
...
```

and in the template:

```
{% for i in range %}
        ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi @qasimalbaqali. Thanks a lot for your answer, but its not what I am asking. I have modified the question. I want to know how to do it asynchronously. The way you have described is not very different to how I am doing right now.

Comment: or maybe I have not understood the solution. I would request if you could elaborate a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a background process for generating the images and saving each generated image link into some storage.

Your first view would trigger the generation process and return an empty page. Then you need another view for returning generated image links in some format (i.e. JSON). From the first view you could poll the second view via AJAX until you get all images.